# Determining the adjacent face of a cube for a given direction (up, down, left or right)

Tags: math

I have a procedurally created cube. I have a reference to each of the six faces which I call front, back, left, right, top and bottom.

```
     ________
   /        /|
  /   T    / |
 |--------| R|
 |        |  |
 |   F    | /
 |________|/
```

Each face has a procedurally created texture. The texture is square and is created by iterating the pixels of a pre-defined resolution size (width == height == resolution size). 
 The x coordinate of the pixel starts from left and increases to the right along the texture. 
 The y coordinate of the pixel starts from the bottom and increases upwards of the texture.

I am now creating a heightmap texture using averaging of the pixels around a given pixel. For this to work, on the occasions when a specific pixel is on the edge of a cubes face, I will need to access the pixel next to it which lies on another face.

My question: Is there a fast, easy way to determine an adjacent face for a given direction (up, down, left or right) starting from any face?

For example: Say I am dealing with the pixels on the Front face, and am iterating the pixels on the right-hand edge (where x == resolution). I know that I need to grab the adjacent pixel on the Right face, because if I walk to the right of the Front face I wrap around onto the Right face.

I could write the logic as a big bunch of conditional checks for every face, covering every scenario, but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: One elegant way would be to define a look-up table with entries such as `rightOf(F)->R, above(F)->T, below(F)->B, ...`.  Absent more details of your implementation and existing data structures you're probably not going to get suggestions much better than this.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that sounds promising. I left it language agnostic to try keep it broad as possible, and I'm only.using simply arrays and lists at the moment and didn't think it would impact the solution.

Comment: Another elegant way is to pad each of the data structures representing a face with *halo* of elements representing the border elements from the neighbouring face.  So each face has 4 extra rows/columns of pixels which duplicate the values on the neighbouring face.